# MaterialDesignExtensions TabControl

Tags: wpf, material-design, tabcontrol

I want to use TabControl with MaterialDesignExtensions.I'm getting an error in the app.xaml. What's the point I'm missing?

Load Nugets:

MaterialDesignColors v1.2.7
MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf v3.2.0
MaterialDesignExtensions v3.2.0

App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="MyApp.App"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
xmlns:culture="clr-namespace:MyApp.Cultures"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MaterialDesignExtensions.Controls;assembly=MaterialDesignExtensions"
>
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="ResourceDictionary1.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/Generic.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignExtensions;component/Themes/MaterialDesignDarkTheme.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignExtensions;component/Themes/Generic.xaml" />
            <!-- primary colors -->
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/MaterialDesignColor.Blue.xaml" />
                </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueLightBrush" Color="{StaticResource Primary100}"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueLightForegroundBrush" Color="{StaticResource Primary100Foreground}"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueMidBrush" Color="#244886"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueMidForegroundBrush" Color="{StaticResource Primary500Foreground}"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueDarkBrush" Color="{StaticResource Primary600}"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueDarkForegroundBrush" Color="{StaticResource Primary600Foreground}"/>
            </ResourceDictionary>

            <!-- accent color -->
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/MaterialDesignColor.Lime.xaml" />
                </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SecondaryAccentBrush" Color="{StaticResource Accent400}"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SecondaryAccentForegroundBrush" Color="{StaticResource Accent400Foreground}"/>
            </ResourceDictionary>

        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Error Message

```
An error occurred while finding the resource dictionary "pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignExtension:component/Themes/Generic.xaml"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this workaround, just include directly the TabControl dictionary from the MaterialDesignExtension 3.2.0

`<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignExtensions;component/Themes/TabControlTemplates.xaml" />`